# How can i change my php variable _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]

Tags: magento-1.9, error

In my site _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] as closed, how can i changed that,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its value can be either off or keep-alive.
Please check instructions here:

https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html

Path of file can be different depending on operating system.
Above instructions are for centos. For other versions like Ubuntu, you need to find apache configuration file accordingly.

Comment: so, this is error of my bulk product export, right

Comment: In my store nearest 16,000 products are there, when i try to export both ways import/export or dataflow both are error. But when i export minimum of data i can able to export my products, which means i can't able to export all my products at a single file.